# Building a multi class logistic regression classifier without SKlearn using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to build a multi class logistic regression classifier using python **without SKlearn library**.

My goal is to write a classifier to classify an app's category(e.g. health, social, etc.) with the tf-idf values in the test data.

What I have got now is a dataframe where data and labels are matched by appname like the image shows.

[image]

In the image, the first array 'data' is the tf-idf values from training data and the second array 'labels' is corresponding to the label of the app.

What I have known now is that I can use logistic regression to learn the weights and biases for each label and then use these values to predict an app's label in test data. And what I can do now is use sigmoid function p = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z)) where z is b+w1x1+w2x2+...+wnxn (b is bias, w is weights and x is the tf-idf value in this case). I am just trying to get weights and bias from the first item. The code is as follows:

```
    # the first training item 
    X = train_data[0, 0:13625]#13625 features
    z = 0.0
    for j in range(len(X)):
        z += W[j] * X[j]
    z += b

    p = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z))  # sigmoid function
    y = train_data[1, i]  # I don't know if it is right to use the second item's feature as a target. 

    # update all weights after each train item
    for j in range(0, 13625):  # gradient ascent log likelihood
        W[j] += lr * X[j] * (y - p)  # t - o gives an "add"
    b += lr * (y - p)  # update bias
```

I don't know if it is right to train weights and bias in this way, anyone has an idea about how I can get weights and bias for each labels in order to classify an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for logistic regression with multiple classes you basically solving this equation 
`Y = WX + B` and you want to increase the `prob(Y=l | x=x)` for each `label=l`

so at the output layer when you get a y vector you need to normalize it probability function, commonly used is [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)

to train the model you use gradient decent, where it basically compute the error of the prediction of the model based on the actual label and use this value to tune both `W` and `B`
you need to do it using the derivatives of the model's functions using also the softmax or the sigmoid derivative

you can find more info [here](https://houxianxu.github.io/2015/04/23/logistic-softmax-regression/)

with complete code, I might give more help

Comment: thanks for reply, I went through the article and it is helpful.